# SAS accessing the macro variable name

Tags: sas

I have some macro variables and each is assigned with a value. How can I get the name of the variables from their value? 
For example I have assigned each person an age value. &Amy=12, &Peter=10.
I also have a macro function calculating something else, say weight.

```
%macro weight(name=);
       %let weight=&name*10;
       %put &name.'s weight is &weight.;
%mend;
```

if I run %weight(name=Amy) I want to get the result as "Amy's weight is 120".
how can i get the result as "Amy" instead of "12"?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the rest of your work where you have the macro varaibles already created and such. In general to resolve those, you need to add more & in front of the macro variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicely evil! That little single quote in the "Amy's" messes things up quite a bit. SAS seems to get confused about trying to evaluate the rest of the macro as a quoted string.
Start with the "magic string" to end all quotes, and make sure you've enabled macro output.

Once you do that, the following should work. Note the additional ampersands before name, as another responder suggested.

```
;*';*";*/;quit;
options mprint;
%let Amy = 12;
%macro weightmacro(name=);
       %let weight=%sysevalf(&&&name..*10);
       %put &name.s weight is &weight.;
%mend;
%weightmacro(name=Amy);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you part of the way there. Note that having the apostrophe there is slightly problematic, you'll need to escape that or quote it out. I've ignored that for now. For the rest of your question:

1. Add more & to resolve a macro variable that's nested
2. Use %SYSEVALF() to do calculations with macro variables

   ```
   %let Amy = 12;

   %macro weight(name=);
          %let weight=%sysevalf(&&&name*10);
          %put &name. weight is &weight.;
   %mend;

   %weight(name=Amy);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If the point is the possessive noun that can be accomplished with %str(%');

```
357  %let Amy = 12;
358  %macro weightmacro(name=);
359         %let weight=%sysevalf(&&&name..*10);
360         %put &name.%str(%'s) weight is &weight.;
361     %mend;
362  %weightmacro(name=Amy);
Amy's weight is 120
```